# Inbuild Functionality to Format Dates using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement to show a date in the format as below in the label control.

**Wednesday 20 Jul 2016 11:31 AM**

Is there any in build functionality available with Jquery without righting my on function to build the string in the specific way as above?

Comment: Answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119138/2010877

Comment: No, jQuery does absolutely not help you with date formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date.format library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format):

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd dS mmmm yyyy h:MM TT");
```

It will return

```
Wednesday 20 Jul 2016 11:31 AM
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library by Steven Levithan. It's just 1.2kb when minified and gzipped.

Here's how to use it:

```
var _date = dateFormat(new Date(), "dddd dd mmm yyyy hh:MM TT"); //use _date variable to display
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this JQuery library : [Date Format](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

```
var now = new Date();
document.write($.format.date(now, "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"));
```